# Data Binding not working for Datagrid in wpf using Collectionview source

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

Here the code snippet for the data grid bind as static source of collection view source.
But the datagrid not showing the required result.

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <local:EDiscoveryCoreDataList x:Key="CoreData"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsCoreData" Source="{StaticResource CoreData}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
            <Canvas x:Name="PanelCanvas1" >
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsCoreData}}"  SelectedCellsChanged="Data_SelectedCellsChanged" SelectionUnit="Cell" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="Data" Canvas.Top="29" Width="1063" Height="536" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <!--<DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key Term" Binding="{Binding KeyTerm }" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key Term Description" Binding="{Binding KeyTermDescription}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Short Hand" Binding="{Binding ShortHand}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rule" Binding="{Binding Rule}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>-->
                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Synonyms}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="View in Document" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Add/Edit Key Terms or Synonyms" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Add/Edit Scoring Answers" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Edit Rule" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid>
```

Data Class:

```
public class EDiscoveryCoreData
    {
        internal string PartNo;
        internal string Section;
        private List<string> _synonyms;
        public string Synonyms
        {
            get
            {
                string returnstring = string.Empty;
                foreach (string synonyms in _synonyms)
                {
                    returnstring += synonyms + "\n";
                }
                return returnstring;
            }

        }
        public string KeyTerm { get; set; }

        public string KeyTermDescription { get; set; }

        public string ShortHand { get; set; }

        public string Rule { get; set; }

        public EDiscoveryCoreData() { }
        public EDiscoveryCoreData(string PartNo, string Section, string KeyTerm, string KeyTermDescription, string ShortHand, string Rule, List<string> synonyms):this() 
        {
            this.KeyTerm = KeyTerm;
            this.KeyTermDescription = KeyTermDescription;
            this.PartNo = PartNo;
            this.Rule = Rule;
            this.Section = Section;
            this.ShortHand = ShortHand;
            this._synonyms = synonyms;

        }


    }
```

Collection Class:

```
    public class EDiscoveryCoreDataList : ObservableCollection<EDiscoveryCoreData>
    {
        //public List<EDiscoveryCoreData> DataList { get; set; }

        public EDiscoveryCoreDataList():base()
        {
            //DataList = new List<EDiscoveryCoreData>();
        }
        public void Add( EDiscoveryCoreData data)
        {
            base.Add(data);
        }

        //public List<EDiscoveryCoreData> GetList() 
        //{
        //    return DataList;
        //}


        public List<string> GetPartNo()
        {
            List<string> partList = this.Select(data => data.PartNo).ToList();
            partList.Insert(0, "All");

            return partList.Distinct().ToList();
        }

        public List<string> GetSection()
        {
            List<string> sectionList = this.Select(data => data.Section).ToList();
            sectionList.Insert(0, "All");

            return sectionList.Distinct().ToList();
        }

        public List<EDiscoveryCoreData> GetFilterData(string partno, string section)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(partno + "======" + section);
            if (section == null)
                section = string.Empty;
            List<EDiscoveryCoreData> filteredData;
            if (partno.Equals("All") && section.Equals("All"))
                return this.ToList();
            else if (partno.Equals("All") && !section.Equals(""))
                filteredData = this.Where(data => (data.Section.Equals(section))).ToList();
            else if (section.Equals("All"))
                filteredData = this.Where(data => (data.PartNo.Equals(partno))).ToList();
            else
                filteredData = this.Where(data => (data.PartNo.Equals(partno) && data.Section.Equals(section))).ToList();
            return filteredData;
        }

        public List<EDiscoveryCoreData> GetFilterData(string searchstring)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(searchstring);
            if (searchstring.Equals(string.Empty))
                return this.ToList();
            else
                return this.Where(data => (data.KeyTerm.ToUpper().Contains(searchstring.ToUpper()))).ToList();
        }

        public List<string> GetListofKeyTerm()
        {
            return this.Select(keyterm => keyterm.KeyTerm).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Populate the collection

```
internal EDiscoveryCoreDataList CoreDataList;
        public Brush BorderColor { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CoreDataList = (EDiscoveryCoreDataList)this.Resources["CoreData"];
            //CoreDataList.Add(new EDiscoveryCoreData("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", new List<string> { "abc" }));
            PanelCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            PanelCanvas1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Data.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
            BorderColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0xff, 0xff, 0xff));
        }


        internal void PopulateMainWindow(EDiscoveryCoreDataList coredatalist)
        {
            CoreDataList = coredatalist;
        }
```

Here I populate the collection by calling the the function from another child window.

Comment: Are you able to see any rows or nothing at all? Also `DataGrid.Columns` part is commented out in your question and `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to false.

Comment: Thanks, after changing the `AutoGenerateColumns` true, Column header is visible but data still not visible.

Comment: Data is not shown because you have not added anything to the collection. Where have you add objects to the instance (CoreData) declared in XAML?

Comment: Here I edit my question add the code snippet.

Comment: Adding part in collection is commented out in constructor.

Comment: That code is for testing. Main population has to be done within `PopulateMainWindow` function. But if i copy that code into populate window and call from a child window it is not working.

Comment: If you uncomment that line does that work? Did you see single row in your dataGrid?

Comment: Yes.I can see the single row.

Comment: So, the problem lies in the method which you haven't shown in the question that how you call this method and how list gets populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First issue where nothing is visible in dataGrid.

You have set AutoGenerateColumns to False and also commented out columns section in XAML. ***Set AutoGenerateColumns to true*** to get the columns.

> Second issue where no row is visible in dataGrid.

In **`PopulateMainWindow`** method you set internal list **`CoreDataList`** to some other reference passed in the method. But this won't update the resource CoreData *(to which your dataGrid is actually binded to)* defined in XAML.

You need to add the object in CoreData list for GUI to get notification which can be done like this:

```
internal void PopulateMainWindow(EDiscoveryCoreDataList coredatalist)
{
    var actualList = (EDiscoveryCoreDataList)this.Resources["CoreData"];
    foreach(EDiscoveryCoreData coreData in coredatalist)
    {
       actualList.Add(coreData);
    }
}
```

---

**Note** - However, ideal sceanario would be to declare list instance in ViewModel and bind Source of CollectionViewSource to that list. So, when you modify that list GUI gets notified and you don't have to fetch instance from XAML resources.